# How to boost search based on index type in elasticsearch or lucene?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have three food type indices "Italian", "Spanish", "American".
When the user searches "Cheese", documents from "Italian" appear to come up at the top. Is it possible to "boost" the results if I were to give preference to say "Spanish"? (I should still get results for Italian, but based on some numeric boost value for index type "Spanish", the ordering of the documents returned in the results give preference to the "Spanish" index. Is this possible in user input lucene and/or ES query? If so, how?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for index-boost? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-index-boost.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a term query with a boost for either the [`_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) field or the [`_index`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) (or both).

Comment: Presently using a string query, is it possible to use it with a term query?

Comment: combine them with a bool

Comment: Do not find any way to boost _type in the official doc, could you give me a sample or a link?  http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 4):

Use a script_score as part of the function score query:

```
function_score: {
  script_score: {
    script: "doc['_type'].value == '<your _type>' ? _score * <boost_factor> : _score"
  }
}
```

Comment: I used `"script": "doc['_type'].value == '35' ? _score * 2 : _score"`, turn out to be `Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingPropertyException[No such property: _type for class: Script4]]`

Answer (score 4):

If querying several indices at once, it is possible to specify indices boost at the top level of object passed to Search API:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/italian,spanish,american/_search -d '
{
    "query":{"term":{"food_type":"cheese"}},
    "indices_boost" : {
        "ilalian" : 1.4,
        "spanish" : 1.3,
        "american" : 1.1
    }
}'
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-index-boost.html#search-request-index-boost

Comment: Alexey, does this require ES 1.7?

Comment: @Alexey Tigarev How can I achieve this using the java client?

Comment: with or without this doesn't seem to change the result score to me

Answer (score 0):

For query-time boosting, queries (ex. [query string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/)) generally have a `boost` attribute you can set.  Alternatively, you can wrap queries in a [custom boost factor](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-boost-factor-query/).  I would probably prefer the former, usually.