# How to boost index type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, ranking

I used to search like this:
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/users/_search`

but users contains user a,b,c like this:
`curl -XGET localhost:9200/users/a,b,c/_search`

`users` is the first index, `a/b/c` is type.

How to boost type `a` in this query? Best with sample code, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to boost search based on index type in elasticsearch or lucene?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727972/how-to-boost-search-based-on-index-type-in-elasticsearch-or-lucene)

Comment: as the example, `users` is the first index, `a/b/c` is type. it's different from that question

Comment: They are the same questions. Care to explain how they're different? Both talk about how to boost a document's score based on its `_type` field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can boost index types using terms query.

First Create some test data (e1,e2,e3 are types and test is the index name):

```
PUT test/e1/1
{
  "subject": "subject 1"
}
PUT test/e2/1
{
  "subject": "subject 1"
}
PUT test/e3/1
{
  "subject": "subject 1"
}
```

Now using term query with custom boost by type:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
         "query_string": {
           "query": "subject"
         }
        },
        { "term" : { "_type" : {"value" : "e3", "boost" : 2.0} } },
        { "term" : { "_type" : {"value" : "e2", "boost" : 3.0} } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Which will generate the result like:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 0.7671045,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "e2",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.7671045,
            "_source": {
               "subject": "subject 1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "e3",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.59740055,
            "_source": {
               "subject": "subject 1"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "e1",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.1289963,
            "_source": {
               "subject": "subject 1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```