# Search across multiple types in elastic search

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

We have two type of documents and they are packages & recipients.
We want to search across both of these types at the same time. We can accomplice this goal via POST to index_name/packages,recipients/_search URL.

Is there any flag which we can use to tell elasticsearch that first search on recipients and then on packages ?
Suppose there are 1K packages and 100recipients. When search it searches across both types but fetches only packages if we do the sorting via id DESC. If we do the sorting id ASC then it fetches recipients too since they are created earlier.

```

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*james* *s*",
      "fields": [
        "_all",
        "packages.recipientId.email"
      ],
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  },
  "size": "10",
  "from": "0",
  "sort": {
    "id": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727972/how-to-boost-search-based-on-index-type-in-elasticsearch-or-lucene

Comment: That was about boosting indices. We are dealing with "types" here. Please see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-index-multi-type.html for more explanation of what we are trying to achieve here.

Is there any way to boost type of mapping i.e. recipients will have more precedence than packages.

We can add a field (hard coded - 2 for recipient, 1 for package) in type mapping and force sorting in descending order of that field. But will that be a cleaner solution ?

Comment: I assume that your Id aren't incremental and that you don't have a creation date to sort on, otherwise I understand that the precedence on types would be achieved by sorting, wouldn't it?

Comment: I have the creation date for package but not for the recipients. I can add creation date for recipients as well and do a reindex.
Still would that solve our case ?

Suppose there are 100 packages having tracking code "SO" and 10-15 recipients having "SO" in their name. 

If user searches for "SO", then we need to display matching recipient in top of the list and then the packages. Also there would be user defined sorting too such as courier name, recipient email id, address etc.

I think ES creates a super set of matching records (consists of both packages and recipients) and then apply.

Comment: the limit to fetch say from 0 to 10 records. Our aim is to bring in matching recipients to top of the list.

Comment: Without user defined sorting, you can achieve what you need sorting by date (if i understand correctly, all recipients have been created earlier than packages). But yeah, custom sorting breaks this.

Comment: It's not necessary that recipients will be created always before packages. But yes a package for recipient will have greater time stamp than the corresponding recipient.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to let receipients appear first, why not adding a field where reciepient has value 1 and package has value 2 and then you sort by this field

Comment: We are using Finder as suggested. It is SF2 framework. However do it solves original problem i.e. giving precedence to "recipients" during cross type search operation ?

Comment: ah i wasnt getting the point, nevertheless you should rather think about your information design, it´s not clear how your desired result should look like, if you want to let receipients appear first, why not adding a field where reciepient has value 1 and package has value 2 and then you sort by this field

Comment: that's what I have mentioned in comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716329/search-across-multiple-types-in-elastic-search/34717630?noredirect=1#comment57181735_34716329